# How does Nginx prevents race condition?

Tags: c, multithreading, nginx, concurrency, race-condition

When thread pool mechanism is enabled in Nginx, some of the aio tasks would be offloaded to a thread pool, which will then notify the main thread when the tasks are done.

But what if a request is timeout while being processed by a thread? `ngx_event_expire_timers` will invoke `ev->handler(ev)` when an event is timeout. How does Nginx prevent such race condition? Please help me out.